# Google AndroidPublisher Subscriptions acknowledge how to

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I created a subscription for my Android app and here's my code to confirm subscription assignments, but I get an error

```
$packageName   =  "com.example.srkn"; 
$productId         =  "com.example.srkn.aylik";
$token =  "<some token here>";

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('ts.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher');
$service = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);

$postBody = "okey";
$para = "test";

$purchase = $service->purchases_subscriptions->acknowledge($packageName, $productId, $token,$postBody,$para);

//echo json_encode($purchase);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to
>   Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Resource_PurchasesSubscriptions::acknowledge()
>   must be an instance of
>   Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_SubscriptionPurchasesAcknowledgeRequest,
>   string given, called in /home/serkanka/public_html/dgr/onayla.php on
>   line 17 and defined in
>   /home/serkanka/public_html/dgr/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/AndroidPublisher/Resource/PurchasesSubscriptions.php:40
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/serkanka/public_html/dgr/onayla.php(17):
>   Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Resource_PurchasesSubscriptions->acknowledge('com.text.spec.s...',
>   'com.text.spec.s...','jlkehndmfjoaenc...', 'test', 'test') #1 {main}
>   thrown in
>   /home/serkanka/public_html/dgr/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/AndroidPublisher/Resource/PurchasesSubscriptions.php
>   on line 40

Comment: Please don't post any tokens inside the code when you are posting a question. You could remove the token and say something like `<some token here>`

Comment: I didn't pay attention thank you

Comment: Worth noting that if your token is to a sensitive service, you should invalidate the existing token. Stack Overflow keeps a diff of what you've posted, so even though the token isn't in the question any more, it's still "on the internet" for a bad actor to find.

Comment: was an invalid token already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postbody (4th parameter) should be an instance of **Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_SubscriptionPurchasesAcknowledgeRequest**

You can set the developerPayload on the object like so:

```
$requestBody = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_SubscriptionPurchasesAcknowledgeRequest();
$requestBody->setDeveloperPayload('your_developer_payload');
```